# Unable to get raw peer certificate in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to download the certificate of my target host in Node JS with no success.

I saw in the documentation that I can get it as a Buffer via socket.getPeerCertificate method:
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/tls.html#tls_tlssocket_getpeercertificate_detailed

I am trying it in the following ways with Node.JS v8.5.0:

```
   var https = require('https');

   var opt = options || {};
   opt.requestCert = true;

   var req = https.request(opt,  function(resp) {
       var cert = resp.connection.getPeerCertificate(true);
       console.log(JSON.stringify(cert, null, 10));
   });

   req.on('socket', function(socket) {
       socket.on('secureConnect', function() {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(socket.getPeerCertificate(true), null, 10));
       })
   });

   return req;
```

Problem: None of the results containing *raw* property, that's all I get (FB for example):

```
{
      "subject": {
                "C": "US",
                "ST": "California",
                "L": "Menlo Park",
                "O": "Facebook, Inc.",
                "CN": "*.facebook.com"
      },
      "issuer": {
                "C": "US",
                "O": "DigiCert Inc",
                "OU": "www.digicert.com",
                "CN": "DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA"
      },
      "subjectaltname": "DNS:*.facebook.com, DNS:*.facebook.net, DNS:*.fb.com, DNS:*.fbcdn.net, DNS:*.fbsbx.com, DNS:*.m.facebook.com, DNS:*.messenger.com, DNS:*.xx.fbcdn.net, DNS:*.xy.fbcdn.net, DNS:*.xz.fbcdn.net, DNS:facebook.com, DNS:fb.com, DNS:messenger.com",
      "valid_from": "Dec  9 00:00:00 2016 GMT",
      "valid_to": "Jan 25 12:00:00 2018 GMT",
      "fingerprint": "93:6F:91:2B:AF:AD:21:6F:A5:15:25:6E:57:2C:DC:35:A1:45:1A:A5",
      "ext_key_usage": [
                "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1",
                "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2"
      ]
}
```

I need the entire certificate, unfortunately fingerprint is not enough.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Works fine on my machine Node v6.11 / Windows. You might wanna check if the API has changed in v8, also update `openssl`.

Comment: I tried it with 6.11.3 on Windows and the results were the same. I will continue with openssl update, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
resp.socket.getPeerCertificate()
```

instead of

```
resp.connection.getPeerCertificate(true)
```

the former uses the method on the tls socket and return more info including a raw field.